# find out the positions of all numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are 64 cells numerated from 1 to 64 and in each cell there is a number from 1 to 64. There is no equal numbers in cells, that's why for each number we have unique cell. For one question you can find out the list of numbers that are situated in cells that you've chosen for a question. How much questions do you need to find out the positions of all numbers?

I know that we need at least 6 questions. We can chose all odd cells for first question and find out numbers, which number of cell is odd. Then we can chose every third cell and so on. All in all in one question we define bit in number of cell for all numbers. But I can't explain why it can not be done for fewer questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With five (or less) questions, assign to each cell a 5-bit string, with the $i$th bit equal to one if that cell is asked for in the $i$th question and zero if it is not asked for. As there are less than $64$ possible 5-bit sequences, there must be some cells that have the same bit sequence. Then these cells cannot be distinguished by the given questions, i.e., if we swap the values of these cells, the answers to all questions are the same and hence the asker cannot distinguish these vriants